# Aggregation with column selecting element based on list of priorities

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I would like to aggregate a list of elements where one column is the urgency. I would like to get a row for each item and take the highest "Urgency" observed for that item based on a list (or mapping).

| Item | Urgency |
| --- | --- |
| A | Normal |
| A | Low |
| A | High |
| B | Normal |
| B | Low |
| C | High |

Expected output:

| Item | Urgency |
| --- | --- |
| A | High |
| B | Normal |
| C | High |

The idea would be like aggregate doing a "max()", but since the urgency is not numerical, I would need some kind of mapping.

Is there a way to do this in one step?

An alternative would be to create a CTE with a case when clause to map each urgency value to an integer. But if possible, I would prefer to do it without that additional step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`max_by`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#id2) aggregate over grouping by `Item` with `case` statement to map urgency into numeric value:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (Item, Urgency) AS (
    VALUES ('A', 'Normal'),
        ('A', 'Low'),
        ('A', 'High'),
        ('B', 'Normal'),
        ('B', 'Low'),
        ('C', 'High')
) 

-- query
select Item,
    max_by(
        Urgency,
        case
            Urgency
            when 'Low' then 1
            when 'Normal' then 2
            when 'High' then 3
        end
    ) Urgency
from dataset
group by Item
order by Item
```

Output:

| Item | Urgency |
| --- | --- |
| A | High |
| B | Normal |
| C | High |

Comment: @Austin yes, all those SQL dialects, there are a lot of interesting features hidden among them.